# How to query from database using Parse via Android

Tags: android, mysql, database, parse-platform, querying

so I was able to store things properly into a Parse database, but I'm a bit confused on how to query things properly using Parse. Here's a method which I try to query a string and return it. It would be really much appreciated if you guys can help!

```
public String query()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() //Runs a new thread here.
    {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e)
        {
            cardName = Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().grabUserCardNameString = testObject.getString("McDonald");
        }
    });
    return cardName;
}
```

}

Then in another activity, I just want to toast that query just to see if I recieved that string.

```
 MyParse example = new MyParse();
 Toast.makeText(this,example.query(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what is going wrong with your current code (e.g., is your query not returning anything, is the query creating an error).

Comment: Oh sorry, so right now, it just Toasts blank. So when i go back to the activity where i put the toast statement, it just toasts a blank box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stepping through these code paths?

From the documentation, which you should always look for answers first. 
https://parse.com/docs/android/api/ (search for FindCallBack)

Since `FindCallBack<>` executes a new background thread, the uithread is not going to wait for it to finish.

Because of this, the method `query()` is not going to wait for the result of the background thread. Which is why `cardName` will return whichever value it was set outside of the scope of the method `query()`.

This is why the Toast message is empty.

What you need to do, is within the `done()` method, either include a callback method to the activity of choice, or execute the Toast message within the `done()` method.  You will need a context within the scope of the done method to do this.